# Problems with gfortran for compiling simple scripts

Tags: fortran, gfortran, fortran90

I am having issues compiling a simple module with gfortran. The module contains nothing and only has a couple of variable declarations:

```
      module global
         implicit none
         double precision :: r = 8
         double precision :: pi = 3.14
         contains        
         end module global
```

When I try to compile this from `cmd` this is what happens:

```
D:\TEMP\FortranTest>gfortran global.f90
C:/Program Files (x86)/mingw-w64/i686-7.1.0-posix-dwarf-rt_v5-rev0/mingw32/bin/.
./lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/lib/../lib/libming
w32.a(lib32_libmingw32_a-crt0_c.o):crt0_c.c:(.text.startup+0x39): undefined refe
rence to `WinMain@16'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

The compiler has no problem doing simple program scripts like "Hello World" type stuff. I'm not sure why it exhibits this behavior with modules.

**EDIT**

In response to VladimirF's comment here is the attempt to compile only as an object file:

```
D:\TEMP\FortranTest>gfortran global.f90 -c global.o
gfortran: error: global.o: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Please use tag [tag:fortran] so that I can close it as duplicate. Use it always because more people can then see your question.

Comment: Thanks. Your program is not a stand-alone program. It is just a module. You can compile it, but you cannot link it to an .exe program. Use the `-c` flag to just compile an object file. Or use `-shared` to compile a DLL or something. If you want a program .exe, you must have `program` and `end program`.

Comment: I tried the -c flag. It didn't work. For this situation I don't want to compile a DLL. Please see edit to original question.

Comment: It should be `gfortran -c global.f90 -o global.o`

Comment: I mean it didn't output an object file...

Comment: Ok yes thanks. That worked.